# How to split a string that is separated by blank spaces that were tabs in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a list of strings:

```
 ["Alpha     Bravo Charlie    Delta",
  "Echo      Foxtrot Golf     Hotel",
  "Inida     Juliet Kilo      Lima"]
```

They look like they were separated by tabs, but if you evaluate the strings, they're separated by multiple `\s` and not `\t`.
What can I do so that I can still separate them by tabs?

Comment: `\s` is not an escape sequence for a space.

Comment: @Krin123, you should add the python tag to your question, I cannot edit as I have hit the review limit for the day

Comment: Your question says "were tabs in python", maybe meaning that's what created the string, but not necessarily the programming language you are using to handle the string now.  If you want your answer in python, please add the python tag to your question.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, that's two of us that think he's intending output with python, so I'll go ahead and change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tab delimit each word you can split and join:

```
l = ["Alpha     Bravo Charlie    Delta",
  "Echo      Foxtrot Golf     Hotel",
  "Inida     Juliet Kilo      Lima"]

l[:] = ["\t".join(s.split()) for s in l]

print(l)
['Alpha\tBravo\tCharlie\tDelta', 'Echo\tFoxtrot\tGolf\tHotel', 'Inida\tJuliet\tKilo\tLima']
```

Answer (score 0):

unless I am missing something couldn't you just find `\s+` 
then replace with `\t`

Answer (score 0):

You do have the problem that there are spaces in what it looks like you're intending to be a single string and not be separated (e.g. "Bravo Charlie").  If you don't want to split on every group of spaces, you need to ensure that there is more than one space in your regex.  However, then if that tab-ish area ever becomes a single-space, you may not split/replace when you need to...

```
split on /\s{2,}/

or replace: /\s{2,}/ with "\t"
```